# Result in CSV/TXT after running the command in PowerShell (Sharepoint Online)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I have this Script where it Prints the sites with more than 500 items and i would like to export the result in CSV or txt file.

Comment: can we see the script you're talking about?

Comment: And/or just a part of the output?

Comment: foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)
{
    $lists = $subweb.Lists
    $ctx.Load($lists)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url

    #output the list details
    Foreach ($list in $lists)
 {
 #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url
 if ($list.ItemCount -gt 3500)
        { 
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"

 
        }
  

 }
}

Comment: this is my script.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable $output contains the items you're printing to the screen then:

$output | Export-Csv C:\temp\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

Edit: Updated to include your code, hope it helps.

```
foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs) 
{ 
    $lists = $subweb.Lists 
    $ctx.Load($lists) 
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

    $output
    #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url 
    #output the list details 
    Foreach ($list in $lists) 
    { 
        #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url 
        if ($list.ItemCount -gt 3500) 
        { 
            $output += $subweb.Url+","+$subweb.Title+","+$list.Title+","+$list.ItemCount
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items" 
        } 
    }
    $output | Export-Csv "C:\Path\to\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: i tried this one but it doesnt work? here is my script.

Comment: foreach ($subweb in $web.Webs)
{
    $lists = $subweb.Lists
    $ctx.Load($lists)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url

    #output the list details
    Foreach ($list in $lists)
 {
 #Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url
 if ($list.ItemCount -gt 3500)
        { 
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "The site URL is" $subweb.Url "List title is: " $list.Title". This list has: " $list.ItemCount " items"

 
        }
  

 }
}